# Не получается заставить работать .htaccess (apache24; windows)

Tags: .htaccess, apache, apache2, apache2.4

Windows 10 64bit. Ставлю Apache Lounge (2.4.23 Win64) в C:/server/apache
htdocs вынес C:/server/htdocs.
Настроил httpd.conf
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so раскомментировал. 
Настройки доступа указал:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "c:/server/htdocs"
<Directory "c:/server/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Вот весь файл httpd.conf (может что-то упускаю)- http://ideone.com/e.js/BhU287

При этом если файл .htaccess пустой, то всё работает. Но если написать что-нибудь, например отключеть кеш, то выдаёт "Internal Server Error"

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</filesMatch>
```

Как быть? Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте раскомментировать

```
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

так как команда `Header` из модуля `mod_headers`.

Answer (score 1):

В полной конфигурации отсутствует имя файла `.htaccess`. Т. е. конфигурация не знает, к какому файлу обращаться.

Добавьте снизу строчку:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```